# Jenkins Parameterized Project For Multiple Parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have Jenkins Pipeline which is triggering for different projects. However the only difference in all the pipelines is just the name.
So I have added a parameter ${project} in parameter of jenkins and assigned it a value of the name of the project.

We have a number of projects and I am trying to find a better way through which I can achieve this.

I am thinking how can we make the parameter run with different parameters for all the projects without actually creating different projects under jenkins.

I am pasting some screenshot for you to understand what exactly I want to achieve.

[image]

As mentioned here, this is a radioserver project, having a pipeline which has ${project} in it.

How can I give multiple values to that {project} from single jenkins job?
IF you have any doubts please message me or add a comment.

[image]

[image: You can see those 2 projects I have created, it has all the contents same but just the parameterized value is different, I am thinking how can I give the different value and make]
You can see those 2 projects I have created, it has all the contents same but just the parameterized value is different, I am thinking how can I give the different value to that parameter.

[image]

As you can see the 2 images is having their default value as radioserver, nrcuup. How can I combine them and make them run seemlessly ?

Comment: You can use [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/)

Comment: @SouravAtta Thanks a lot for suggesting this plugin . Can you tell me exactly how I can proceed further ?

I am able to download it, but I am confused which option to select here from Basic, Multi-level or JSON Parameter Type ?

Comment: @SouravAtta I have added the image as well for you to check.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad... You can use [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) which is better option than `extended choice parameter`. Also, you can find the examples on how to use `Active choice parameter` in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think I get your question correctly. do you want a choice parameter which will populate a list of value dynamically so that you can choose one when you trigger the job ? 
Can you please elaborate more on your expectation of the Job with a small example ?

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel I have a pipeline which is having a $project parameter. I want to give input of project name in all those parameter {project} 
Currently I have created a separate job for all the 9-10 projects which will accept just a different parameter. I am editing my question for better understanding. You can check and suggest

Comment: Hi @SouravAtta , I actually tried to use the active choices plugin but did not really get if it is helping my needs or I am not getting how to make it work. 

Simply, 
I want to give different parameters to {project} in different times of the day. 

Like one day I want the job to execute with ${project} with string parameter 'test1' , next day I want to execute ${project} with string parameter 'test2' .
And I want this all in one single  job of jenkins. Can we achieve that? What are the ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

> I hope this will help. Let me know if any changes required in answer.

You can use conditions in Jenkins. Based on the value of ${PROJECT}, you can then execute the particular stage.

Here is a simple example of a pipeline, where I have given choices to select the value of parameter `PROJECT` i.e. test1, test2 and test3.

So, whenever you select test1, jenkins job will execute the stages that are based on `test1`

**Sample pipeline code**

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            choices: ['test1' , 'test2', 'test3'],
            description: 'PROJECT NAME',
            name: 'PROJECT')
    }

    stages {
        stage ('PROJECT 1 RUN') {
            when {
                expression { params.PROJECT == 'test1' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, test1"
            }
        }
        
        stage ('PROJECT 2 RUN') {
            when {
                expression { params.PROJECT == 'test2' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, test2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

1. when `test1` is selected

[image]

[image]

2. when `test2` is selected

[image]

[image]

---

**Updated Answer**

Yes, it is possible to trigger the job periodically with a specific parameter value using the Jenkins plugin [Parameterized Scheduler](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/)

After you save the project with some parameters (like above mentioned pipeline code), go back again to the `Configure` and under `Build Trigger`, you can see the option of `Build periodically with parameters`

**Example:**

I will here run the job for `PROJECT=test1` every even minutes and `PROJECT=test2` every uneven minutes. So, below is the configuration

[image]

```
*/2 * * * * %PROJECT=test1
1-59/2 * * * * %PROJECT=test2
```

> Please change the crontab values according to your need

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sourav for this. But how can we automate it? 
I want to build it periodically, like I want the test1 to implement today automatically and next day {project} should automatically take the parameter of 'test2' and run. Can we achieve that too ?

Comment: Or else, even if it is possible like , the first it should take parameter of 'test1' , it should get completed successfully, and then it should take 'test2' as {project} and so on..?
There is not just a single place where we used {project} , there are about 5-6 places where that parameter will be used in a single pipeline, so I am afraid that it should not get mixed.